# Help with querying a DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have this initial code:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("column2", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("column3", typeof(string));
        table.Rows.Add(1, 0, "a");
        table.Rows.Add(2, 1, "b");
        table.Rows.Add(3, 1, "c");
        table.Rows.Add(4, 3, "d");
        table.Rows.Add(5, 3, "e");
```

How can I do these using LINQ?

a. Return the DataRows whose values in column1 also appears in column2.

So far, I did this:

```
var x = (from t1 in table.AsEnumerable()
         select t1.Field<int>(0)).Intersect
        ((from t2 in table.AsEnumerable()
         select t2.Field<int>(1)).Distinct());
```

Bu the problem is, only the values of column1 is returned, which I use a `foreach` on. Probably because of the `select t1.Field<int>(0)` part, but I don't know how to return the DataRows itself.

b. Return the values of column3 whose values in column1 also appears in column2.

Almost the same question as [a]. I can only return the column1 row since I already used it. I don't know how to return the DataRows and other columns (e.g. column3) except column1.

I have also tried this:

```
var x1 = from t in table.AsEnumerable()
         select t;
var x2 = (from t in table.AsEnumerable()
          select t.Field<int>(1)).Distinct();
```

I was hoping to use Intersect() on x1 and x2, but I don't know how. Especially since x1 is kind of like a DataRow[] and x2 like an int[].

c. Using the answer in [a] for another query.

Or using something from a LINQ for another LINQ. i have **no** idea at all how to do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach:

```
a)    var result = (from t1 in table.AsEnumerable() 
                   join t2 in table.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<int>(0) equals t2.Field<int>(1)  select t1).Distinct();
```

The query above returns`IEnumerable<DataRow>`.From this result you can select values of column3 like `t2.Field<int>(2)` for b) scenario.

Comment: What about [c]? should I just expand the LINQ instead? Or can I use the var result on another LINQ?

Comment: If you need the output of [a] query use the value of the `result`.

Comment: Also, I think you meant `select t1` there.

Comment: Right. I've changed the query and added `Distinct()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering, join + distinct behaves exactly like Intersect, right? How can I do the same thing using Intersect()?

Comment: You could do something like `var resultInteresct =   table.AsEnumerable().Select(i=>i.Field<int>(0)).Intersect(table.AsEnumerable().Select(j=>j.Field<int>(1)));` to get the `int` values that exists in the columns. After that you can do another query on table to select the Rows with those value.

Comment: I did this: `var x = (from t in table.AsEnumerable() select t.Field<int>(0)).Intersect((from t2 in table.AsEnumerable() select t2.Field<int>(1)).Distinct());` What I don't know is how to use `x` or the `resultIntersect` to select the Rows with their values.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new class for the three columns.  Then create an Iqueryable or List for the new class and add the table rows into that.  Then the Linq expression should work.

**Class**

```
public class myClass
{
    public int column1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int column2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public stringcolumn3
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

**Linq**

a. Return the DataRows whose values in column1 also appears in column2.

```
var x = (from l1 in myList
         where (from l2 in myList
                select l2.column2).contains(l1.column1)
         select l1);
```

b. Return the values of column3 whose values in column1 also appears in column2.

```
var col3Values = (from l1 in myList
                  where l1.column2 = l1.column3
                  select l1.column3);
```

Comment: Is the myList like this: `List<int> myList = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5};`(contents of column1)?

Comment: No... Create a class with three properties.  List<myClass>.

Answer (score 0):

With help from guys here, and some other sites, I just found out how to actually do [b] above.

This returns the values in column3 whose values in column1 **does not** appear in column2:

```
   from t in table.AsEnumerable()
       join t2 in table.AsEnumerable().Select(i => i.Field<int>(0)).Except(table.AsEnumerable().Select(j => j.Field<int>(1)))
       //the inner Select() returns column1 whose values in it also appears in column2
       //I can use either this or the first LINQ I made above
       //By the way, I said **does not** because I don't think I can use inner join on the opposite of [b]
       //unlike the Select() with lambda above; I can just change the Intersect() to Except() :)
       on t.Field<int>(0) equals t2
   where t.Field<int>(1) > 2          //If I need some other condition
   select t.Field<string>(2);
```

For [c], I made another table:

```
        DataTable tableA = new DataTable();
        tableA.Columns.Add("columnA", typeof(string));
        tableA.Columns.Add("columnB", typeof(string));
        tableA.Rows.Add("apple", "red");
        tableA.Rows.Add("banana", "yellow");
        tableA.Rows.Add("carrot", "orange");
        tableA.Rows.Add("dog", "commonly brown");      //ok, I can't think of a fruit/vegetable that starts with 'd' right now...
        tableA.Rows.Add("eggplant", "purple");
```

And renamed the first table to table1 to avoid/minimize confusion

```
    var x = from tA in tableA.AsEnumerable()
        from t1 in (
            from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
            join t2 in ((from t2_1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                            select t2_1.Field<int>(0)).Except
                        ((from t2_2 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                            select t2_2.Field<int>(1))).Distinct())
            on t1.Field<int>(0) equals t2
            where t1.Field<int>(1) > 2        //extra condition
            select t1.Field<string>(2))
        where tA.Field<string>(0).StartsWith(t1)
        select tA;
```

This returns Rows in tableA whose columnA starts with the returned table1's column3, whose column1 values does not appear in column2 and has a value greater than 2 in its column2.