# Another help with querying a DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the same question as [before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178567/help-with-querying-a-datatable-using-linq) I'm still using the same sample.

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("column2", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("column3", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add(1, 0, "a");
    table.Rows.Add(2, 1, "b");
    table.Rows.Add(3, 1, "c");
    table.Rows.Add(4, 3, "d");
    table.Rows.Add(5, 3, "e");
```

And I did this to return the values of column3 whose values in column1 also appears in column2:

```
var x = (from t1 in table.AsEnumerable()
         select t1.Field<int>(0)).Intersect
        ((from t2 in table.AsEnumerable()
         select t2.Field<int>(1)).Distinct());
```

How can I get the values of column3 based on the LINQ above?

I can use the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178567/help-with-querying-a-datatable-using-linq):

```
var result = (from t1 in table.AsEnumerable() 
              join t2 in table.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<int>(0) equals t2.Field<int>(1)
```

Although I *think* I can't use this on the opposite of the first LINQ, which could be translated as 'Return the values of column3 whose values in column1 **does not** appear in column2.' However, I can change my above LINQ to an `Except()` instead on `Intersect()`. I just need to know how to use the `var x` to get either the collection of Rows or just the values of column3.

Comment: Why are you even using a `DataTable`? Strongly typed collections are usually much better.

Answer (score 0):

these should give you what you want:

```
// collection of datarows
var rows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(i => i.Field<int>(0) == i.Field<int>(1));

// collection of strings (field 3 of rows)
var rowvalues = rows.Select(j => j.Field<string>(3));
```